# Boost asio and winhttp

Tags: boost-asio

If we use boost asio library how do we send the credentials to the Web Server. For example, Winhttp library allows to set credentials using Winhttpsetcredentials. How do we do the same in boost?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/aa384112 - winHttpsetcredentials

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp - Sample example

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add the code to send the credentials you need to the code that sends the other headers.

```
request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

You can add code to send credentials anywhere in there. (Obviously, before the double line-ending that ends the headers.)

Comment: Does boost provide any libraries for NTLM?